# How to use EntityFramework BulkInsert?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to use, [this](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/), but the system can not find the methods of lib...
Nothing that is specified in the documentation of the lib. is running, for example: GetContext() is not found, the own BulkInser is not found .... I put at the top of my code the Using of lib, but nothing works .....
How I can make to use that Lib ? ( I'm using the VS2013 )

My code:

```
using EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Extensions;

using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
{
    var ctx = new MyDBCon.MyDBDataContext();

    ctx.BulkInsert(linhas); // error in BulkInsert ( method not found )

    ctx.SubmitChanges();
    transactionScope.Complete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the library...

```
using EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Extensions;
```

Add this to the top of your class.